# Polyline points are not accurate while moving

Tags: android

When you draw a polyline, those points near the turns are not accurate while moving they are placed on the top of the buildings and sometimes instead of a proper polyline there is a line from the source to destination.What I want to do is a polyline must stick on to the road.So how do I fix this?

I am following [this link](https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android):

Please find the [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWOT5.png) for more clarification.

Comment: Report the issue in github as well

Comment: @Gurleen you need to study about the direction api....